# How to config IIS for TLS certificate and is required any change in my project?

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, ssl

I have a ASP.net web Project.

Many month ago my coworker tested my project in IIS with SSL self-certificate According to below link :

https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-in-iis-7.html

unfortunately my coworker doesn't be hear anymore and I don't know a lot about SSL Configuration in Project ! but I am expert in ASP.net and C# project

Right now our customers say "we need this project with TLS(V 1.2) Protocol Support" !

I know a little about TLS and I don't know how do I change my project for TLS certificate and what should I do for test it in IIS v 8.0 ? I heard TLS is next generation of SSl Protocol .
my OS is Win 8 .
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I search in google and at last o found that I do this in 2 below step:

1- at first, I should handle SSL in IIS 
https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-in-iis-7.html

2- at second, I must execute some script in power shell :
https://www.hass.de/content/setup-your-iis-ssl-perfect-forward-secrecy-and-tls-12

Comment: You should accept your own answer. However, the self-signed certificate link is too old to be used. Most people today should use PowerShell to generate their own certificates, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps